# Can variable be skipped in a list if it is empty?

Tags: list, scala

I am writing an API which has loads of optional parameters which are passed to a query.

Problem is that query is a list of all parameters and if one of them is `None` I get an error. Can the variables  which are empty just to be completely skipped?

Some code:

```
val param01 = BSONDocument(/*Query parametters*/)
val param02 = BSONDocument()//Causes an error
val query = BSONDocument(BSONArray(param01, param02))
```

P.S. Matching all the prams to `Some` or `None` is not an option there are way to many of them

Comment: Slightly difficult to tell exactly what you're looking for but maybe have a look at what `flatMap` will do to a `Seq[Option[Foo]]` ?

Comment: Can't you do something like ```params.filter(_.isDefined)```?